# Excel: Edit Column Data by Evaluating Data from Other Column with Matching Data from Third Column

Tags: excel, concatenation

We have data from our system that contains demographics data for insurance choices. The employees could have selected insurance for themselves, insurance for them and their children, insurance for them and their spouse, or insurance for their whole family (them, their spouse, and their children). Traditionally we would group them by total number (Employee, Employee+One, or Family), and we would not care if the combination included children or spouses, but the carrier wants it differently.

- Employee
- Employee + Spouse
- Employee + Child
- Employee + Children
- Family

We need to retain the number of rows because each row if for a different person, but Member IDs are shared between the employee and any dependents.

I am trying to find a way using a formula, preferably because then it can be used by more people, to look at all the same **Member IDs** (could be 1 to infinity - the highest I've seen so far is 7) and then another column that says either **self, Spouse, or Child**, and add one of the above designations depending on the outcome.

So essentially I would have an additional column (let's say Column H) that would say Employee, Employee + Spouse, Employee + Child, Employee + Children, or Family depending on what combination of self, Spouse, and Child were found in Column B for the matching Column A IDs.

Below is an example of the data. I've removed columns that aren't relevant (email address, home address, social, etc.) that are included in the actual data, and I have changed all of the names and Member IDs, but the data with which we are working is very similar.

Most of the solutions I have seen result in one row with the concatenated data, which would still need to be parsed into the appropriate designations, but I need it to be repeated for all rows. For instance, in the example below:

- Row 2 and Row 3 would both have Employee + Spouse
- Row 4 would have Employee
- Rows 5-7 would have Employee + Children
- Row 8 would have Employee
- Rows 9-15 would have Family
- Row 16 and Row 17 would have Employee + Child

[image: Excel Data Example]

Comment: This *may* be too much for an excel formula (I could be wrong), but could be easily achieved with VBA - are you completely against a VBA solution?

Comment: What if a spouse or child does not have the same last name as the employee? (This isn't that uncommon.) In that case there would be no way to link them to that family?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Last name should be irrelevant as they're being linked by member ID (column A)

Comment: @dwirony I thought that as well, except that the entire Bush and Obama family have the same ID. :|

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Hmmm I assumed that was just 1 big family with 5 children, didn't even notice the last names! ha

Comment: @dwirony Actually... I guess technically Francine Bush could be married to Alex Obama, and they have a ton of kids, some with Bush as last name, others with Obama as last name? If this is an actual family (and not just an arbitrary example), that would be amazing! hahah

Comment: LOL! Yes. Francine Bush and Alex Obama are married in that scenario. The Member ID is the unique identifier. Sadly, they are a fake family from my imagination. 

I am not opposed to VBA, but if the solution is VBA, I would be the only person, most likely, who could apply it, and I am looking for a solution I can give to others. I am going to try some of the ones below, but I appreciate the help - VBA or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This normally entered formula works for me

`=CHOOSE(MATCH(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,{"Spouse","Child"})*{100,1}),{0,1,2,100,101}),"Employee","Employee + Child","Employee + Children","Employee + Spouse","Family")`

I'm assuming every ID will have a "Self" entry, the above doesn't check that - formula assigns a value 100 to spouse and 1 to a child and the resultant total for an ID will tell you whether it's a family or one of the other combinations.

If you want you could include "Self" in the calculations and return "Error" if there isn't one for any ID, e.g.

`=CHOOSE(MATCH(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,{"Self","Spouse","Child"})*{1000,100,1}),{0,1000,1001,1002,1100,1101}),"Error","Employee","Employee + Child","Employee + Children","Employee + Spouse","Family")`

The order of the data doesn't matter

Comment: Wow, great approach. I always use `MATCH` for exact values (e.g. `MATCH(<value>,<array>,0)` and I usually forget that sometimes you can exploit `MATCH` for inexact values. You accomplished this very elegantly. Great formula. +1

Comment: This was beautiful. I feel like I was so close. I was using Countifs and Match, and I just got nowhere near this.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the same solution to @dwirony except without VBA in case VBA is not an option for you.

Paste the following array formula into cell `G2` and drag down as necessary (line breaks added for readability):

```
= CHOOSE(MIN(IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$20="Spouse")+0,($A2=$A$2:$A$20)+0)=0,5,4),
  MMULT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW($A$2:$A$20)>0)+0),(IF($A2=$A$2:$A$20,$B$2:$B$20)=
  {"self","Spouse","Child"})+0),{1;1;2})),
  "Employee","Employee + Spouse","Employee + Child","Family","Employee + Children")
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also note in this example the data goes down to row 20, but you'll have to adjust the cell ranges accordingly based on whatever your data is.

See below for working example.

[image]

Comment: I like both! I wish I could add two checks because I used both formulas (I didn't try the VBA), and they both worked. :-)

Comment: @katz2row No hard feelings. You should accept the best answer (which you did).

Answer (score 1):

Probably a sloppy solution, but it works nonetheless - just using some booleans and looping through the memberID and relationship columns matching values.

```
Sub GetBenefitOption()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim memberID As String
Dim spouse As Boolean, child As Boolean, children As Boolean, family As Boolean

For i = 2 To lastrow
    memberID = Range("A" & i).Value

    For j = 2 To lastrow
        If Not Range("A" & j).Value = memberID Then
            If j = lastrow Then
                Range("G" & i).Value = "Employee"
            End If
        Else
            If Range("B" & j).Value = "Spouse" Then
                spouse = True
            ElseIf Range("B" & j).Value = "Child" And child = True Then
                children = True
            ElseIf Range("B" & j).Value = "Child" Then
                child = True
            End If
        End If

        If spouse = True And child = True And children = True Then
            family = True
        End If
    Next j

    If family = True Then
        Range("G" & i).Value = "Family"
    Else
        If children = True Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = "Employee + Children"
            child = False
        Else
            If child = True Then
                Range("G" & i).Value = "Employee + Child"
            Else
                If spouse = True Then
                    Range("G" & i).Value = "Employee + Spouse"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

spouse = False
child = False
children = False
family = False

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Just FYI, this is possible without VBA. See my answer. Still gave you a +1.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Aha, I knew someone would come along with an array formula! Nice solution as well, +1 to you too

Comment: Haha, ever since your first comment "This *may* be too much for an excel formula (I could be wrong)", I thought to myself: "Challenge accepted".